# NaN shows up in calculations

Tags: javascript, calculation

i got stuck in this function `multiplyUsed()`.
I'd like to sum all the boxes with two checkbox's conditions.
Finally, if i check the box `Quality` the results shows up `NaN`. Why it has happened? the values are filled out in the boxes `Sta` and `Sta+`.

```js
function sumUpUsedCar() {
  var standartUsedLoan = Number ( document.getElementById("standartUsed").value);
  var standartPlusUsed = Number ( document.getElementById("standartPlusUsed").value);
  var prUsedCompleted = document.getElementById("prUsedCompleted");
  var prUsedDoesntCompleted = document.getElementById("prUsedDoesntCompleted");
  if (prUsedCompleted.checked) {
    document.getElementById("sumUsedVehicle").innerHTML = (standartUsedLoan * Number(0.04)) + (standartPlusUsed * Number(0.065));
  } else {
    document.getElementById("sumUsedVehicle").innerHTML = (standartUsedLoan * Number(0.03)) + (standartPlusUsed * Number(0.045));
  }
}

function multiplyUsed() {
  var qualityCompleted = document.getElementById("qualityCompleted");
  var sumUpUsedC = Number (document.getElementById("sumUsedVehicle");

  if (qualityCompleted.checked) {
    document.getElementById("sumUsedVehicle").innerHTML = (sumUpUsedC * Number(0.03));
  }
}
```

```html
<form>

  <label class="showLabel5" for="usedCar"><b>Sta</b></label>
  <input class="standartUsed" type="number" min="100000" max="100000000" id="standartUsed" onchange="sumUpUsedCar()">

  <label class="showLabel6" for="usedCar2"><b>Sta + </b></label>
  <input class="standartPlusUsed" type="number" min="100000" max="100000000" id="standartPlusUsed" onchange="sumUpUsedCar()">
</form>



<div class="usedVehicle2"><b>Additional </b></div>

<label class="container2" for="yes"><b> Yes</b>
   <input type="checkbox" class="input2" name="yes" id="prUsedCompleted" onclick="prUsedSelection(), sumUpUsedCar()">
    </label>

<label class="container2" for="no"><b> No</b>
     <input type="checkbox" class="input2" name="no" id="prUsedDoesntCompleted" onclick="prUsedSelection()">
    </label>


<div class="mainbox5">


  <div class="quality"><b> Quality</b></div>

  <label class="container3" for="yes"><b> Yes</b>
   <input type="checkbox" class="input3" name="yes" id="qualityCompleted" onclick="multiplyUsed()">
  </label>

  <label class="container3" for="no"><b> No</b>
 
   <input type="checkbox" class="input3" name="no" id="qualityDoesntCompleted">
   </label>

  <div class="overall"><b>overall:</b></div>

  <table class="tableOverall">



    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td id="sumUsedVehicle"></td>

  </table>
```

Comment: `"message": "ReferenceError: qualitySelection is not defined"`

Comment: `onclick="qualitySelection(), multiplyUsed()"` won't work. Also, it does not make any sense to use checkboxes for yes/no choices - this is what radio buttons are for.

Comment: @connexo why? onclick can have any valid JavaScript and comma separated of two expressions is valid JavaScript.

Comment: I deleted `qualitySelection()`

Comment: It's still in your code. `<input type="checkbox" class="input3" name="no" id="qualityDoesntCompleted" onclick="qualitySelection()">`

Comment: I changed it all. You can see it above. Unfortunately, it hasn't still worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line

```
document.getElementById("sumUsedVehicle").innerHTML =  (sumUpUsedCar * Number(0.03));
```

`sumUpUsedCar` is a function. You probably want a function call there `sumUpUsedCar()`. When converting a function to a numeric value, as required for multiplying, its value is `NaN`.

---

after your edit, in the function `multiplyUsed` the expression `document.getElementById("sumUsedVehicle").value` is `undefined`, because the DOM element has no `value`attribute. Use

```
var sumUpUsedC = Number (document.getElementById("sumUsedVehicle").innerHTML);
```

instead.

Comment: I changed it all. You can see it above. Unfortunately, it hasn't still worked

Comment: Frankly, i removed value attribute from `document.getElementById("sumUsedVehicle").value`, but i still haven't realized where i have to use `innerHTML`. Please give me a clue

Comment: `var sumUpUsedC = Number (document.getElementById("sumUsedVehicle").innerHTML);`